# Android SafeArgs Unresolved Reference

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, navigation, fragment

I can't seem to be able to get SafeArgs to work:

My XML navigation file contains:

```xml
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_adv_list"
        android:name="com.example.drawerexample.ui.AdvListFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_show_adv_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_adv_list" >
        <argument
                android:name="onlyUserAdvs"
                app:argType="boolean"
                android:defaultValue="true" />
        ...
     <action
            android:id="@+id/nav_adv_list_to_my_adv_list"
            android:name="com.example.drawerexample.ui.AdvListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_adv_list">
            <argument
                android:name="onlyUserAdvs"
                app:argType="boolean"
                android:defaultValue="true" />
        </action>
</fragment>
```

This is because I need the argument to be `false` by default and `true` when coming from a specific fragment.
Anyway, my Kotlin code is the following:

```kotlin
class AdvListFragment : Fragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
      ...
      private val fragmentArgs : AdvListFragmentArgs by navArgs()

     fun useArgs() {
         val x = arguments.onlyUserAdvs
     }
}
```

Which is fine because when writing code Android Studio recognizes the binding and even suggests me the (only) variable present. However, when building the app I get:

```
.../ui/AdvListFragment.kt: (54, 63): Unresolved reference: onlyUserAdvs
```

I've read the documentation many times so I think my gradle is ok, but anyway here is the project level build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.2")
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and the app level gradle.build:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.drawerexample"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'

}
```

I've also tried reopening Android Studio, reopening the project, clean-building the project and rebuilding the project with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

change in the app gradle.build
from
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
to

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
```

I had the same problem and it helped me

Comment: No, `.kotlin` for only kotlin module . And without .kotlin for Java/kolint project

Comment: Worked for me, even though I am using kotlin. Navigation version 2.5.1 and Kotlin version 1.7.10

Comment: Worked for me too (and I'm a newbie). Yes I'm working in Kotlin environment, but despite that I found that I HAD to use the JAVA: `def navigationVersion = "2.5.3"` and not the KOTLIN: `val navigationVersion = "2.5.3"` my app build.gradle file's "dependencies". Why is that??? I dunno. But the above fix worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

I only use Kotlin and I also had navigation version 2.4.1 for all components and plugins.

**Changing version to 2.5.1 helped me.**